# C++: recommended design pattern for subsets of class functionality?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, pointer-to-member

I am seeking advice on a design pattern that is a good fit to my needs:

Within my C++ project, one particular pure-virtual class will represent the superset of all related functionality for a certain concept, and the concrete classes derived from that pure-virtual class will each be some different limited subset of that superset.  Only 1 instance of any of these concrete classes will exist at runtime.

If I were programming in C, I would likely choose to implement this as a struct of function pointers, with NULLs for any missing functionality.  But that doesn't feel very satisfying for C++.

About the only idea I can think of is a class with every member function as 'protected', and a matching set of 'public' member function pointers.  The constructors would be responsible for initializing the MFPs to either NULL or the address of the appropriate member function, depending on what functionality that class provides.

But that is really only marginally more C++-ish than the C-struct-of-function-pointers that I first mentioned above.  And, perhaps it is good enough.  But I am wondering if anyone can suggest a more satisfying, insightful design pattern for this scenario.

I am open to any generally accepted practice.  STL is fine.

<s>**UPDATE**: The reason why the MFP approach isn't very satisfying, is that I will have to implement do-nothing stubs for the ones that don't apply-- because of the pure-virtual base class-- even though I would be setting their respective MFPs to NULL.</s>  On further reflection, this update was completely bogus.  (They will not be do-nothing stubs, they will be the functionality that is useful, in the cases where NULL isn't used for the MFPs.  I think I was tired.)

**UPDATE 2**: An analogy: My project supports hardware modules that can be swapped out.  They are all basically the same category of functionality, but vary in features and capability.  At startup, I must detect which hardware module is actually attached, and instantiate the appropriate class.  But I don't want the code that uses that class to have special knowledge of each of the classes; I want the class to advertise what functionality it is providing.  (Sometimes, two hardware modules will identify as the same type ID, but upon a capabilities probe, one will indicate functionality that the other does not.)

Comment: (I am not positive this question is a good match for S.O., but I don't know where else to ask.)

Comment: Most probably this design is starting out on the wrong foot. But there have been cases where something like this has been appropriate. One solution is to factor the functionality out into pure interfaces, which each concrete class can inherit and implement at will. Then client code can use e.g. `dynamic_cast` to discover at run time what functionality is there. Or in template code it can use `std::is_base_derived` (which as I recall has its arguments in the wrong order, but anywa). But do think about whether this complication -- which is what it is -- serves a useful purpose. Does it?

Comment: I updated my question with an analogy, exemplifying the reasons why I feel I need this type of approach.  In particular, this part:  "Sometimes, two hardware modules will identify as the same type ID, but upon a capabilities probe, one will indicate functionality that the other does not."

Comment: As for me "struct of function pointers" sounds quite C++'ish.

Comment: sounds like one of the factory creational design patterns might be useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design requirement violates a very important OOP [principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).
If a class or a function depended upon that "superset" interface, then the compiler would never be able to enforce type-safety - you'd essentially be fighting against it, and for what?

I recommend that you [segregate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) your interfaces, and make one concrete (possibly pure virtual) class that implements all of them. This design pattern has a name - it's called [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

**Update** I now read *your* update, and I believe you need a facility for promoting objects.
There are 2 kinds of promotions:

- Implementation promotions:
  This is where you essentially replace the implementation of an object. This can either be done by the [state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) pattern, or by placement-newing your object to one with a different VTABLE.
- Functionality promotions:
  This is where you *add* functionality, as in more functions. You can do this by having a map from a name of a hardware module to a variant pointer of it. When you promote an object to a different class, you simply replace the pointer variant. E.g., if your first mapping was from "COM1" -> `GenericSerial*`, then you now set "COM1" -> `SpecializedSerial*`. You can work with a variant library such as [boost's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

```
interface All {
    void f1();
    void f2();
    void f3();
}
abstract class AllABC implements All {
    public void f1() {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
    }
    public void f2() {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
    }
    public void f3() {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
    }
}
class F12 extends AllABC {
    public void f1() {
        System.out.println("f1");
    }
    public void f2() {
        System.out.println("f2");
    }
}
class F13 extends AllABC {
    public void f1() {
        System.out.println("f1");
    }
    public void f3() {
        System.out.println("f3");
    }
}
public class So20511733 {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        All f12=new F12();
        f12.f1();
        f12.f2();
        All f13=new F13();
        f13.f1();
        f13.f3();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is reasonable, and is essentially the approach I went with (2 months ago,) despite accepting Yam's answer.  Originally I wanted a solution where the client code queried for some particular support before attempting it, but eventually just settled for exceptions when unsupported.